# ASP.net MVC how to get the value of the ID field for the list of items?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, lookup

I have an application, that shows list of items bound to a typed model.

In the list every item has an ID from a lookup table.

How to show the value of the lookup data for each item instead of IDs?

The best way has to link a html dropdownlist to each ID, from where I would be able to choose the appropriate value.

Thanks in advance

Gabrile

Comment: Not entirely sure what your data looks like from your description. Are you trying to show just a DropDownList or are you trying to have rows of data each with a DropDownList of the same entries?

Comment: My view has some textboxes, and a dropdownList to populate a new item, and a list of items, that I added. 
When I add a new item, I fill the textboxes, choose a value from the dropdown, and after being posted the newly added item shows up in the list, but naturally I get the ID values instead of values.
So I wwant to bind somehow in the view a dropdown to each item in the list, to show the values, and for choose an other value for the ID if I want.

Comment: Is your DropDownList statically defined or are you creating it from a collection of data?

Comment: The typed view bound to the model object, in wich I created a selectList.
This selectlist is bound to the Html.DropDown in the view, where I select a value from, to add to the new item an id. Then this new item I get back in the list of the same page after posting.

Comment: In my sample app. I statically defined the selectList, but in a real appliacation I would get the values from the database table.

Answer (score 1):

Well the first step is to make sure you get all of the values that will be in the DropDownList. You should be able to easily fetch this from your database.

Set the text of the DropDownList items to the text value for the lookup item, and set the value to the ID of those same items.

When creating the DropDownList make sure to set the Selected one to be the option which matches the ID of your modeled data item.